# Prevent automount of USB HDD at login

Tags: 19.10, ubuntu-gnome, automount

This issue is particularly for logging in from the lock-screen, not startup.

I have a USB hard-disk drive permanently connected to my PC. I want to leave it unmounted for the most part, only mounting when I explicitly do so. The issue that this drive is automatically mounted every time I log in from the lock screen.

I have tried setting the `noauto` flag in `/etc/fstab` for this drive (by UUID), without any change in behaviour.

How can I ask GNOME to refrain from mounting this drive when I log in?

Comment: FYI:   Don't forget your 19.10 release reaches EOL today, so *release-upgrade* asap to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2020-July/005494.html    https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

Comment: @guiverc, Thanks for the reminder :D The issue will probably persist into 20.04 too

Comment: A drive declared in /etc/fstab that is set to not automount will not automount. I estimate that your fstab entry might be wrong/invalid. If it is only happening when returning from the lock screen, then there is erroneous behaviour indeed. Better then to first confirm whether the issue is there in 20.04 also. Check fstab with `findmnt --verify`

Comment: @vanadium, `findmnt` says "Success". So, I think the fstab entry is, indeed, valid. The full entry for this drive is `UUID=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx /mnt/<uuid> ext4 nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

Comment: Are you sure it is effectively mounted? (you can see that in the output of `mount`.). Might be that it is just displayed in File manager, without being mounted.

Comment: @vanadium, it is properly mounted all right. I initially noticed this problem when some other daily scripts which wanted to mount this volume complained that it was already mounted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The `/etc/fstab` entry for this HDD had the `x-gvfs-show` option set, which according to [the docs](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/blob/master/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt) is meant to control whether or not this drive appears in the user interface. I'm copying the relevant section below:

```
If the directory for a device is known and outside /media, $HOME
(typically /home/foo) or /run/media/$USER then the device is not shown
in the user interface. Additionally, if any of component directories
in its directory starts with a dot ("."), the device is not shown
either. This policy may be overriden by use of the options x-gvfs-show
and x-gvfs-hide.
```

For some unknown reason, `x-gvfs-show` overrides `noauto` even in GNOME version 3.36. As a result, the HDD was being automatically mounted at login.

Answer (score 0):

While your point about **x-gvfs-show** is correct, the order in which they are applied, from left to right, is the ultimate reason why it did not work with the original sequence.

My understanding is that if the option sequence was

```
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show**,noauto**
```

the **noauto** would have overriden the **x-gvfs-show**.

Comment: I am currently unable to test this hypothesis. Is there any documentation which specifies your point about ordering?

Comment: When I had tried to resolve other issues in the past, I had come across a reference that mentionned the option order being applied from left to right, and that the last option evaluated would be applied.

Comment: Your solution did not cover the scenario I experienced in solving a different problem by option order.  From the man page for mount, noauto  Can only be mounted explicitly (i.e., the -a option will not cause the filesystem to be mounted).  That statement in the man page leaves no doubts as to what should happen, or am I wrong?

Comment: Relating to GVFS, please also refer to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/527 .